# onClick select tag dropdown options toggle div container

Tags: angular, typescript

```
    <div>
  <select label="Payment Options">
    <option *ngFor="let option of paymentOptions" [value]="option.value">{{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- Selection Option 1 -->
<div>
  Container 1
</div>

<!-- Selection Option 2 -->
<div>
  Container 2
</div>

<!-- Selection Option 3 -->
<div>
  Container 3
</div>

<!-- Selection Option 4 -->
<div>
  Container 4
</div>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-option-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './payment-option-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-option-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentOptionDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  paymentOptions: DropdownItemOption[] = [
    {
      label: 'Test 1',
      value: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      label: 'Test 2',
      value: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      label: 'Test 3',
      value: 'Test 3'
    },
    {
      label: 'Test 4',
      value: 'Test 4'
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I have a drop down with different options along with four div tags and I want to write a function to toggle the containers `onclick` of drop-down options, for example, if I select option 1 (Test 1) from the drop down I want to display container 1 div, like that the rest of options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
  <select label="Payment Options" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <option *ngFor="let option of paymentOptions" [value]="option.value">{{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="selectedValue">
 <!-- Selection Option 1 -->
<div *ngSwitchCase="paymentOptions[0].value">
  Container 1
</div>

<!-- Selection Option 2 -->
<div *ngSwitchCase="paymentOptions[1].value">
  Container 2
</div>

<!-- Selection Option 3 -->
<div *ngSwitchCase="paymentOptions[2].value">
  Container 3
</div>

<!-- Selection Option 4 -->
<div  *ngSwitchCase="paymentOptions[3].value">
  Container 4
</div>
</div>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-option-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './payment-option-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-option-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentOptionDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  paymentOptions: DropdownItemOption[] = [
    {
      label: 'Test 1',
      value: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      label: 'Test 2',
      value: 'Test 2'
    },
    {
      label: 'Test 3',
      value: 'Test 3'
    },
    {
      label: 'Test 4',
      value: 'Test 4'
    }
  ];

  selectedValue = 'Test 1';    
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

add control varaiable (selectedValue) for binding with the seleceted value and use *ngSwitch to show the conteiner you desire

Comment: It's hard coded right, what if I want to make it dynamic ?? I mean if I moved the options still I want to open the correspondent div containers @Mariano Calcagno

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" (ngModelChange)="setOption($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of paymentOptions" [value]="option.value">{{ option.label }}
    </option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="selectedOption == paymentOptions[0].value">
    Container 1
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedOption == paymentOptions[1].value">
    Container 1
</div>

// Similarly for Container 3 & 4
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-payment-option-dropdown',
    templateUrl: './payment-option-dropdown.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./payment-option-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentOptionDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

    selectedOption: any = '';

    paymentOptions: DropdownItemOption[] = [
        {
            label: 'Test 1',
            value: 'Test 1'
        },
        {
            label: 'Test 2',
            value: 'Test 2'
        },
        {
            label: 'Test 3',
            value: 'Test 3'
        },
        {
            label: 'Test 4',
            value: 'Test 4'
        }
    ];

    setOption(event){
        this.selectedOption = event;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard coded right, what if I want to make it dynamic ?? I mean if I moved the options still I want to open the correspondent div containers

Comment: its depends on the data you display in the container `Container 1`

Comment: I mean let’s just say I shuffled my options and in the drop down the first one is test 4 if I click on it I should show div container 4, I’m really not worried about what inside the div